# draw line graph in ggplot after summarizing value in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Click to see dataFrame]

I have a data frame as shown in image below, Now I want to plot a line graph showing hour as x axis and mean(count) in y with color being days. I have tried but the visual came out empty

[image: Click to see how my plot came up (empty)]

```
ggplot(data=temp,aes(hour,mean(count),color=days))+geom_line() # This is what I tried.
```

I checked melt function also to try to do this but couldn't figure out.

Structure of Dataframe using dput

```
structure(list(days = structure(c(2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
), class = "factor"), hour = structure(c(20L, 17L, 15L, 7L, 8L, 
10L, 7L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23"), class = "factor"), `mean(count)` = c(222.576923076923, 177.567307692308, 252.836538461538, 9.51428571428571, 184.922330097087, 161.480769230769, 68.3009708737864)), .Names = c("days", "hour", "mean(count)"), row.names = c(44L, 41L, 135L, 151L, 32L, 106L, 
79L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please, add a section of your dataset using dput(). A pic is not useful

Comment: Added. I hope this is what you asked for!

Comment: I think the issue is in the column name mean(count). Please, replace it e.g.  mean_count. This works well: ggplot(data=temp,aes(x = hour,y = mean_count,colour = days))+geom_line()

Comment: Hey, I tried that. Doesnt work same O/P. Get below msg 
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group
aesthetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column names with a parenthesis are non-standard variable names.  As such, you'll need to use backticks to reference the column.

Also, since the `hour` variable is a factor, you'll need to use a `group` aesthetic so the lines will render correctly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

temp <- 
  data_frame(days = factor(rep(c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), each = 24),
                           levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")), 
             hour = factor(rep(0:23, 7), levels = 0:23),
             "mean(count)" = rnorm(7*24) 
             )

ggplot(temp) +
  aes(x = hour, y = `mean(count)`, group = days, color = days) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]